# Find exact sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How may I find sum of this series using Stirling formula?
Thanks for any help.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{2n\choose n}^{n!}}{n^{n^n}}$

$1st$ term equals to $2$,
$2nd$ term equals to $36/16$,
$3rd$ term equals to $20^6/3^{27}$.

Comment: So, you want an approximation for this sum? Who's to say it has a closed form answer?

Comment: yes, but not numerically

Comment: Approximations are numerical ... please explain a bit more. Writing some context could help here :-)

Comment: it can be approximation but with mathematical explanation it is also good.

Comment: I'm guessing OP just wants the Stirling formula applied to all factorial terms and then simplified as much as possible?

Comment: I don't see that point of using Stirling's formula here. The $4^{th}$ term in the sum is already around $1.4 \times 10^{-110}$. To get an approximation accurate to first $100$ decimal places, one just need to keep the first three term in the sum...

Comment: This reference may be helpful: http://www.amazon.com/Inequalities-Applications-Engineering-Michael-Cloud/dp/3319053108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{2n\choose n}^{n!}}{n^{n^n}} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2})^{n!}}{n^{n^n}} $$

Employing the approximation I get:
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 \pi n} (2n/e)^{2n}}{(\sqrt{2 \pi n} (n/e)^n)^2}\right)^{\sqrt{2 \pi n} (n/e)^n}}{n^{n^n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{2^{2n} }{\sqrt{\pi n}}\right)^{\sqrt{2 \pi n} (n/e)^n}}{n^{n^n}} $$

$$= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(\sqrt{2 \pi}\frac{n^{n+ 1/2}}{e^n}(2n\log 2 - (1/2)\log \pi - (1/2)\log n)\right)}{n^{n^n}}$$

At this point I don't see that this will simplify to a nice answer. But hey, I tried for you.